# how to get the token of current user when logged in vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

i'm trying to show a component if a user is logged in vuex

this is my state

```
const state = {
  status: "",
  token: localStorage.getItem("token") || "",
  
  user: {}
};
```

this is my getters

```
const getters = {
  isLoggedIn: state => !!state.token,
  authStatus: state => state.token
};
```

this is my response

```
state{
status:"success"
token:"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5c"
}
getters{
isLoggedIn:false
authStatus:undefined
}
```

i don't know why isLoggedIn:false when i'm getting the token

Comment: also do check your `authStatus`, its undefined which means state.token is `undefined`. I suppose the token value you have pasted on response is not how its actually is

Comment: shouldn't that be `window.localStorage`?

Comment: @Amaarockz window.localStorage still  the same

Comment: cool buddy, just asking :)

Comment: how about the first question that i asked, did you check that

Comment: if token contains a string, `isLoggedIn` will definately return true. Hence, looks like your token is empty.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal but in myresponse i'm getting the token